# kaleidoscopic effect on a triangle

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Let $\triangle ABC$ and straightlines $r$, $s$, and $t$. Considering the set of all mirror images of that triangle across $r$, $s$, and $t$ and its successive images of images across the same straightlines, how can we check whether $\triangle DEF$ is an element of that set?

Given:

1. Points: $A(1,1)$, $B(3,1)$, $C(1,2)$, $D(n,m)$, $E(n+1,m)$, $F(n,m+2)$, where $n$ and $m$ are integers numbers.
2. Straightlines: $r: x=0$, $s: y=0$ and $t:x+y=5$.

No idea how to begin.

Comment: Have you calculated the reflections of $ABC$ across $r$, $s$, and $t$ yet?

Comment: Sounds like you have the generators of a group... Not sure if that's a very useful way to frame the problem, though.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Yes. Across r $(-1,1)$, $(-3,1)$, $(-1,2)$;  across s $(1,-1)$, $(3,-1)$, $(1,-2)$; and across t $(4,4)$, $(4,2)$, $(3,4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an image of your coordinate system, your three lines of reflections, and your original triangle. You can draw in mirror triangles pretty easily, and with a few of these, you will probably find a pattern. (I created my illustration using [Cinderella](http://www.cinderella.de/), which comes with a tool to define transformation groups.)

[image: Cinderella screenshot]

As you can see, there are locations $m,n$ for which the triangle $DEF$ is included. Note that $E$ is the image of $C$ and $F$ is the image of $B$, though. I'll leave it to you as an excercise to find a possible combination of reflections which maps $\triangle ABC$ to $\triangle DEF$.

Comment: The illustration helped a lot. Therefore if $(n-6)$ and $(m-6)$ are multiples of 10 then $\triangle DEF$ is an element of the images set, right?

Comment: @RicardoCruz: right.